# How to prevent windows from automatically using next best static route

Tags: networking, windows-10, openvpn, network-adapter, static-routes

I have two VPNs: VPN1 automatically connects pre-login and acts like a consumer VPN by pushing all traffic through it. Users have no control over this - it needs to connect prelogin which means it runs by the system and not on the user profile, which is desirable anyway since I want to force all traffic to be encrypted to the VPN1 gateway.

I want users to be able to manually connect to VPN2, which provides access to a network with more sensitive resources. VPN2 is the only way in or out of that network - the firewall blocks everything else. When you connect to VPN2 alone you have no internet access.

The issue is that when the user is connected to both VPNs, their client can act as a bridge exposing VPN2 to the internet via VPN1. I thought I had a solid way to preempt this by pushing the same static route that VPN1 uses to tell Windows to push all traffic through VPN2, except set the route metric to 1 so it has priority. That would push all traffic through VPN2, and its firewall would block anything going external and thus no internet.

But it appears that Windows 10 automatically tries the next best static route. So after a few failed attempts to reach the destination through the VPN2 gateway, it will use VPN1 despite the higher metric.

Is there a way to prevent this failover? Or any documentation on it so that maybe I can game it? Such as it attempts 3 gateways before it gives up so I add 4 higher priority static routes that run into a firewall?

Comment: I’m curious. How to force all traffic through VPN 1 but still connect to VPN 2? Wouldn’t that mean VPN 2 is established within the VPN 1 tunnel? That seems inefficient. VPN2 would only be “exposed” to the internet if you allow routes or IP addresses other than the one you assign to the client through the VPN and the client does in fact, “bridge” the connections or become a router. It’s not really clear what exact scenario you are trying to prevent.

Comment: Does the 2nd gateway actually respond with an ICMP error report (e.g. "Net unreachable" or "Administratively prohibited"), or does it just quietly drop the traffic?

Comment: @Appleoddity It isn't efficient in that it's doubling bandwidth and double encryption isn't necessary, but the issue is connecting to vpn pre-boot requires the system to run it, and the user cannot have local admin privileges. That puts a lot of restrictions on the ability to do anything with that first connection.

It doesn't matter what restrictions I put on VPN2 because VPN1 is wide open. It creates two parallel connections on two adapters even though VPN2 is technically being routed through VPN1.

Comment: @grawity It just quietly drops the traffic. If I initially connect to VPN2 and ping google, the requests will time out. If I go try to load a bunch of pages and then ping google again, it will succeed. When I run a tracert it will always try to go through VPN2 first, the requests will time out after they hit the firewall as desired, but after 5 failed attempts it starts to succeed presumably due to switching to the route through VPN1.